# How to get windows network reporting to point to a different partition

Tags: windows, reporting

My C: drive is small, and it's getting filled with .hdmp files from Windows Error Reporting.  I've searched, but can't find a way to get it to dump files on my D: drive instead.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't... Windows error reporting saves the dumps locally. You can however disable the Windows Error Reporting, and the .hdmp files.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754364.aspx

Comment: By "local" you're implying that my D: drive is not local, even tho it's a partition on the same drive.  Not trying to split hairs, just want to be clear -- you're saying the .hdmp files have to be on the same partition as the windows installation?

Comment: Yes, on the system drive.